# how to prevent multiple php script inside jquery to execute on button click

Tags: php, jquery

on my page I have two forms and jquery to execute php

```
<form>
.
.
.
<button id="btn1"></button>
</form>

<form>
.
.
.
<button id="btn2"></button>
</form>

<script>
document.ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
<?php php function to insert values in database ?>
});
$("#btn2").click(function(){
<?php php function to insert values in database ?>
});})
</script>
```

on clicking either button, both php scripts are running, what to do to prevent the other.

Comment: You need to show us some real code, not pseudo-code reducing the problem to a state that doesn't show us any details.

Comment: Keeping in mind that both php blocks inside the click handers are going to both execute before the markup is returned to the client

Comment: the best way is to find which button is clicked in order to process its PHP function, use ajax